# How to make a variable based on a one column table in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using Snowflake I have a table as follows:

```
ID EMAIL              value
01 berry@grape.com    30
02 burger@king.com    50
03 jessica@rabbit.com 100
...
```

I want to make a new variable labeling each entry in the table as "internal" vs. "external". All internal users are listed in the following table

```
EMAIL
burger@king.com
ronald@mcdonald.com
peanut@planters.com
```

The resulting join of these two tables should be with a new variable called "user_type" , internal when an entry is in table2, external when it's not.

```
ID EMAIL              value  user_type
01 berry@grape.com    30     external
02 burger@king.com    50     internal
03 jessica@rabbit.com 100    external
```

I think I can do this with one singular join and an CASE WHEN, but unsure how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `left join` and `case` expression:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when t2.email is null then 'external' else 'internal' end) as user_type
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.email = t2.email;
```